# How to make an XML-RCP request through Fiddler?

Tags: http, fiddler, rcp

I am using Fiddler to troubleshoot an XMLRCP connection to MiniBlog. Here is the MiniBlog Api: http://bigfont-miniblog.azurewebsites.net/metaweblog. How would I request for the blogger.getUsersBlogs FROM Fiddler? Here is my initial attempt:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're really *troubleshooting a connection* to the service in question, you should use Fiddler to capture the request from the client to the server. If you then wish to play around with modifications to that request, drag/drop the Session from the Web Sessions list to the `Composer` tab and modify to your liking.

It's pretty likely that you need to use a `POST` request whose body contains one or more parameters, including a `username` parameter specifying which user's list to return.